# Crystal Report size increase issue because of multiple images in report in ASP.NET MVC (latest version - 13.SP.32)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

I have a member list report with total members of 500+ with each member image. when I print Crystal Reports without image, it's working fine. When I print with images, it crashes with an error of "processing time limit exceeded".

I have tried to increase the temp folder memory size but error still exists.

Can you please suggest what to do?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Crystal is **not resizing the images**. That can cause a huge increase in memory consumption.

If the image size on the report is different from the source image size, convert the images to the size in the report before consuming them.

Some of the 3rd-party Crystal Reports UFLs (User Function Library) listed on Ken Hamady's site [here](https://www.kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#ufl) provide a function that allow the 'Graphic Location' expression of a dummy image to resize a target image on-the-fly and consume the resized version.